# changing multi select to single select for hasMany dependencies in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a 'Flight' entity with 2 'belongToHasMany' dependencies (one is 'crw' - a crew member and 'actingas' - a crewmember type, for example, an 'instructor' or 'safety pilot').
All controllers and views were created through the 'bake' utility and all CRUD operations work as expected.

I need to change how the default drop-down selects are created for 'crw' and 'actingas'. Right now they multi-selects, I need to make them single-selects so I can add several combinations of 'crw-actingas'.

I looked over a couple of older tutorials but got nowhere with them to be honest.

I experimented with the 'edit' view of a 'Flight'.
The generated fieldset looks like this:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Edit Flight') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('date');
        echo $this->Form->control('total_duration_of_flight');
        echo $this->Form->control('actingas._ids', ['options' => $actingas]);
        echo $this->Form->control('crw._ids', ['options' => $crw]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

... so copied and pasted the generated html after fiddling with it (changing names of the controls):

```
    <div class="input select">
    <label for="actingas-ids">Actingas</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="actingas[_ids]" value="">
    <select name="actingas[_ids][]" multiple="multiple" id="actingas-ids-0">
        <option value="1">CFI</option>
        <option value="2">Safety Pilot</option>
        <option value="3">CFII</option>
        <option value="4">MEI</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="input select">
    <label for="crw-ids">Crw</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="crw[_ids]" value="">
    <select name="crw[_ids][]" multiple="multiple" id="crw-ids-0">
        <option value="2">Rob</option>
        <option value="3">Tim</option>
        <option value="4">Bob</option>
        <option value="5">Rog</option>
        <option value="6">Bart</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

... of course, the values from the auto-generated selects get saved but not the hacky ones. But I don't get any errors either.

The 'edit' function in 'FlightController':

```
 public function edit($id = null)
{
    $flight = $this->Flight->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Actingas', 'Crw']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

        //var_dump( $this->request->getData() );
        //phpinfo();
        //die();

        $flight = $this->Flight->patchEntity($flight, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Flight->save($flight)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The flight has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The flight could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $actingas = $this->Flight->Actingas->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $crw = $this->Flight->Crw->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('flight', 'actingas', 'crw'));
}
```

Flight table:

```
    class FlightTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('flight');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Actingas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'flight_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'actingas_id',
            'joinTable' => 'flight_actingas'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Crw', [
            'foreignKey' => 'flight_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'crw_id',
            'joinTable' => 'flight_crw'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->dateTime('date')
            ->requirePresence('date', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('date');

        $validator
            ->numeric('total_duration_of_flight')
            ->requirePresence('total_duration_of_flight', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('total_duration_of_flight');

        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Actingas table:

```
    class ActingasTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('actingas');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Crw', [
            'foreignKey' => 'actingas_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'crw_id',
            'joinTable' => 'crw_actingas'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Flight', [
            'foreignKey' => 'actingas_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'flight_id',
            'joinTable' => 'flight_actingas'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->allowEmpty('title');

        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

CRW table:

```
    class CrwTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('crw');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Actingas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'crw_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'actingas_id',
            'joinTable' => 'crw_actingas'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Flight', [
            'foreignKey' => 'crw_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'flight_id',
            'joinTable' => 'flight_crw'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->maxLength('title', 255)
            ->allowEmpty('title');

        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that simply

```
echo $this->Form->control('actingas._ids', [
    'options' => $actingas, 
    'multiple' => false,
    'type' => 'select'
]);
```

should work

Comment: ... hm, tried that, the framework seems to ignore it.

Comment: Add `'type' => 'select'`. I just tried and it worked. Actually I don't see the point of having a non-multiple select in a belongsToMany relationship. Anyhow